# How to implement iPhone look alike alert boxes in sencha touch?

Tags: javascript, iphone, sencha-touch, extjs, alert

I am trying to implement the alert boxes in sencha touch application which looks similar to iPhone alert boxes.

I have used `Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Hello World')` to implement the alert boxes but it looks different from iPhone alert boxes. I have attached both the images for reference.[image: iPhoneAlertBox]

[image: Sencha Alert box]

Any guidance will be very helpful.

Thank you,

Comment: I believe, I have to use phonegap to achieve this functionality. 'navigator.notification.alert' will give the native alert box for iOs. Not sure though

Comment: Why don't you add some styles to the message box and create a similar alert.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add

```
requires: ['Ext.device.Notification']
```

to register notification method then use below code to alert

```
Ext.device.Notification.show({
    title: 'Test Adi',
    message: 'Is your email address is: adnan@sencha.com',
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
    callback: function(button) {
        if (button == "ok") {
            console.log('Verified');
        } else {
            console.log('Nope.');
        }
    }
});
```

instead of

```
Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Hello World')
```